# Tinting color over an <img> element in CSS

Tags: html, css

### Objective

To have a colored overlay on top of an image when its containing `<li>` has a class of `active`. It should look similar to this

[image]

also the default overlay on all images is dark. But needs to be replaced when active. The image underneath is a lighter black and white image.

### Background

I have found various tutorials and answers here about how to have a colored overlay on top of an image. But Most have the "image" be a `background-image` of that a div.

In my case **I cannot change the current order of elements in the html**.

### Question

How can i modify the CSS only to have a colored layer over the image?

The default image is in black and white. They will have a dark overlay when the `<img>` has a class of `bw`.

If the containing `<li>` is active, the dark overlay will be cancelled out by the orange overlay.

So it seems that I would have to use a lot of inheritance to have success. Perhaps have the `active` class after the `bw` class?

```
li img.bw {
  background: rgb(3,3,3); /* dark overlay */
  opacity: .9;
}

li.active img.bw {
  background: rgb(246,137,28); /* orange */
  opacity: .5; 
}
```

### Code

Demo on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/WQmEqQ)

#### HTML

```
  <li class="active">
    <a href="">
      <img class="bw" src="http://www-tc.pbs.org/prod-media/newshour/photos/2013/07/10/Tesla_circa_1890_slideshow.jpeg">
    </a>  
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="">
      <img class="bw" src="http://www-tc.pbs.org/prod-media/newshour/photos/2013/07/10/Tesla_circa_1890_slideshow.jpeg">
    </a>
  </li>
```

#### CSS

```
/* demo only */
.li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
img { height: 200px;  width: 160px;}
/* styles for overlay */
li img.bw {
  background: rgb(3,3,3);
  opacity: .9;
}
li.active img.bw {
   background: rgb(246,137,28);
   opacity: .9;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you want, but does this demo behave how you're expecting? http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/ec6e314207d72ba3cdc5ec5d50638660/

Comment: @JoshRutherford that works. However the overlay should only happen when the `<img>` inside of it has a `class="bw"`. or no overlay when hovered over. I can modify from here. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good solution to achieve your desired effect is to use the `::after` *pseudo-element*:

```css
li, li a, li a img {
display: inline-block;
width: 120px;
height: 160px;
}

li {
position: relative;
margin-right: 20px;
}

li a {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}


li a::after, li.active a::after {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 12;
width: 120px;
height: 160px;
}

li a::after {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

li.active a::after {
background-color: rgba(255,128,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="active">
    <a href="">
      <img class="bw" src="http://www-tc.pbs.org/prod-media/newshour/photos/2013/07/10/Tesla_circa_1890_slideshow.jpeg">
    </a>  
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="">
      <img class="bw" src="http://www-tc.pbs.org/prod-media/newshour/photos/2013/07/10/Tesla_circa_1890_slideshow.jpeg">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works well. I forgot to mention that there should be no background color when you hover over. I solved this by adding this additional rule `li.active a:hover::after { background-color: transparent; }`